# What is the correct regex pattern to use to clean up Google links in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

As you know, Google links can be pretty unwieldy:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=some+search+here&source=hp&newwindow=1&ei=A_23ssOllsUx&oq=some+se....
```

I have **MANY** Google links saved that I would like to clean up to make them look like so:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=some+search+here
```

The only issue is that I cannot figure out the correct regex pattern for Vim to do this.

I figure it must be something like this:

```
:%s/&source=[^&].*//

:%s/&source=[^&].*[^&]//

:%s/&source=.*[^&]//
```

But none of these are working; they start at `&source`, and replace until the end of the line.

Also, the `search?q=some+search+here` can appear anywhere after the `.com/`, so I cannot rely on it being in the same place every time.

So, what is the correct Vim regex pattern to use in order to clean up these links?

Comment: Try it like this with a capture group `:%s/\(https\?:\/\/www\.google\.com\/search?q=[^&]*\)[^[:space:]]*/\1/g`

Comment: Are the urls ever quoted? Eg `href="http://www.google.com/…"`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you, but that only works if the `?q=` is immediately after the `search/`.

Comment: @Bohemian No, not really.

Comment: @Brian But you do want to keep until `?q=` or `&q=` ?

Comment: I would like to keep the `q=searchterm01+searchterm02+searchterm03` **or** just be able to easily eliminate anything with the pattern like this: `&source=...` or `&ie=...` or `&newwindow=...`. essentially anything that **starts** with an ampersand, up to, but not including, the next ampersand.

Comment: @Brian That would be for example like this `&[^&[:blank:]]+` or `&[^\s&]+` if that is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example can easily be dealt with by using a very simple pattern:

```
:%s/&.*
```

because you want to keep everything that comes before the second parameter, which is marked by the first `&` in the string.

But, if the `q` parameter can be anywhere in the query string, as in:

```
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&newwindow=1&q=some+search+here&ei=A_23ssOllsUx&oq=some+se....
```

then no amount of capturing or whatnot will be enough to cover every possible case with a single pattern, let alone a readable one. At this point, scripting is really the only reasonable approach, preferably with a language that understands URLs.

--- EDIT ---

Hmm, scratch that. The following seems to work across the board:

```
:%s@^\(https://www.google.com/search?\)\(.*\)\(q=.\{-}\)&.*@\1\3
```

- We use `@` as separator because of the many `/` in a typical URL.
- We capture a first group, up to and including the `?` that marks the beginning of the query string.
- We match whatever comes between the `?` and the first occurrence of `q=` without capturing it.
- We capture a second group, the `q` parameter, up to and excluding the next `&`.
- We replace the whole thing with the first capture group followed by the second capture group.

Comment: Wow, that works nicely ... thank you! Out of curiosity, what does "`{-}`" do?

Comment: `\{-}` is a non-greedy quantifier that matches as few as possible of the preceding atom. In this case, it is used to make sure that the capture group really stops at the first `&`. See `:help \{`.